# QGIS: why doesn't the "graduated" classification work for my column?

Tags: qgis

I'm new to QGIS so bear with me. I need to show something on a map using the "graduated" classification. The thing is the program doesn't give me this option. I believe it's been reading the column as text instead of numbers, but how can I change that?

Comment: Please include what version of QGis you are using. Answers may vary depending on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the type of data in the column by right-clicking in the layer, click in 'layer properties' and have a look at the tab 'source fields'. You will see the data type there. If you confirm that is your problem, one option is to create a new column with the correct data type (numeric), and use the field calculator to copy all the values to the new column. Then, delete the old one.

Answer (score 1):

First of all check in your layer properties what kind of vector file your have. You can do this to go to Layer properties --> Fields and in the field Type name you will see Integer, Integer 64 or real. If it says string then you will have to make a new field with a numeric type. You can do this by adding a new field and then hit the fieldcalculator button or push (ctrl+i). Check the update existing field box and select the field you want to change. Go to "Fields and Values" and dubbel click the field you want to copy.

[image]

If you do have an numeric field then you can go to layer properties --> symbology and change the singel symbol into graduated.

[image]

Then enter field you of which you want to present the value and hit the classify button below to make a graduated classification.

[image]